# Change Location In tempnam

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am having some trouble providing the directory path in `tempnam();`. When i use `tempnam('', 'xyz');`  , the file is getting stored in `tmp` directory. But i need to store the file in a specific directory permanently. I am using CodeIgniter. I want to save the files in folder `docs` which is located in the same directory as `application` and `system`. What location should I give in `tempnam();`?
 UPDATE: I tried providing with location path ie `tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/exotel/docs' , 'xyz');` but still the file is saved in `tmp` folder

Answer (score 0):

RTLM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

As per the above docs, if the specified directory does not exist, tempnam() may use the system temp dir. You're specifying an empty string directory (`''`), which will not exist, so PHP is free to use whatever directory it wants.

Try

```
$temp = tempnam('/path/to/where/you/want/the/file', 'xyz');
```

instead.

Comment: I tried giving `$temp_file_uri = tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/exotel/docs', 'xyz');` even still its going into `tmp` folder. docs directory exists in `/var/www/exotel/docs`

Answer (score 0):

see documentation for tempnam [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php). First parameter is a directory.

Example from docs:

```
<?php
$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "FOO");

$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, "writing to tempfile");
fclose($handle);

// do here something

unlink($tmpfname);
?>
```

Comment: I tried giving `$temp_file_uri = tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/exotel/docs', 'xyz');` even still its going into `tmp` folder. docs directory exists in `/var/www/exotel/docs`